# Is there an interactive interpreter for Java?

Tags: java, compilation, interpreter

I want to execute java commands interactively from shell: is there a way to do so?

Comment: uhuh? "Write the method itself in cmd"? Do you mean you want an interactive interpreter?

Comment: In a way similar to the REPL of Python of Lisp?

Comment: I think this person would like to be able to do something like the following hypothetical example `java --cmd 'int x=5; System.out.print(x);'`

Comment: @ninjagecko: yeah, but it doesn't make even the slightest sense to do such thing in Java, given its verbosity...

Comment: For that you write a program in Java, compile, execute it in the command line. And that will behave has you expected.

Comment: @akappa "you do not want to" != "doesn't make sense"

Comment: @Isaac Truett: in programming they are pretty much the same thing: if something is fugly, then it indeed doesn't make sense

Comment: @akappa Great. Get back to me when you actually find a programming language that some significant portion of the developer world doesn't consider "fugly."

Comment: @Isaac Truett: huhu? I love Java, I'd just hate to write a bunch of "class X { public static void main(...) { ... } } in an interactive shell just to evaluate a command.

Comment: @akappa The whole point of having an interactive shell that interpreted Java snippets is so that you _wouldn't_ have to do all that. It would be like watch expressions in an IDE; individual statements evaluated immediately in a persistent JVM. What you seem to be envisioning is a real-time compiler/automatic Java executor.

Comment: @Isaac Truett: yeah, but this pretty much implies defining a new *language* which is closely tied to Java but isn't Java. BeanShell makes a lot of sense, but it isn't just java, just something (closely) related.

Comment: @akappa Why would you need a new language? Start Eclipse, set a breakpoint, then write Java in a watch expression, and see it executed. Now take that functionality and make an interactive shell out of it (that's the non-trivial part, of course). Why do you need a new language?

Comment: @Isaac Truett: we need a new language because we were talking about writing stuff in an interactive shell, not in the execution window of an IDE. The point is that, in a "pure" interactive shell, you need to write something which is well-defined in itself and not given a "context". Since interactive shells are something which are used to experiment on-the-fly, you need something *comfy* - hence the need of something less "heavy" on syntax.

Comment: @akappa You're confusing preference with need again. And your comment about context makes no sense. A shell environment is a context.

Comment: @Isaac Truett: I'm not confusing anything: programming is all about *comfort*, otherwise we'll just stick with assembly. And a "shell environement" is a context, but with a whole different meaning (it doesn't define any "structure" relevant to Java, while the command executed in a window is executed inside a method of a class already defined, with a given state. Bad example...).

Comment: I use this for one liners: https://gist.github.com/davethomas11/c6a9f0f75ff7cd64f993ca289de060c0 When I want to test a java api. Note the limitations of this, only code you'd want to run in one main function. Not intended to be anything more.

Comment: What you want my friend is jshell. just type `jshell` in terminal that should do.. you can read more on jshell here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/snippets.htm#JSHEL-GUID-614373AD-8D94-462A-B05E-DFA35DF098C9

Comment: JShell [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8)

Comment: as the two comments above state, that exactly JShell  (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jshell/introduction-jshell.html) answers the OP's question, it should be reopened and answered properly, as nobody searches the whole comments in that list. Therefore I vote to reopen the question and let someone answer this.

Answer (score 7):

The closest thing I'm aware of is [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/).

Answer (score 6):

Not an interactive interpreter or a shell, but consider **[Eclipse scrapbook pages](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cscrapbook.htm)** a possible option.

> The Java development toolkit (JDT)
>   contributes a scrapbook facility that
>   can be used to experiment and evaluate
>   Java code snippets before building a
>   complete Java program. Snippets are
>   edited and evaluated in the Scrapbook
>   page editor, with resultant problems
>   reported in the editor.
>
> From a Java scrapbook editor, you can
>   select a code snippet, evaluate it,
>   and display the result as a string.
>   You can also show the object that
>   results from evaluating a code snippet
>   in the debuggers' Expressions View.

Bonus: the scrapbook is an Eclipse default feature, so it's not required to install anything you don't already have.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using DrJava http://drjava.org/. It could serve your purpose

Comment: Handy tool. You do have to stub out a basic console app, though.

Comment: The Interactions  pane is a little useful, actually what I want is something just like SnippetCompiler for C# and LinqPad for LINQ. The interactions pane is not very handy to write a chunk of code.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't possible (as far as I have found) to write and run arbitrary java snippets interactively from the command line.

I was looking for something similar a few years ago. There's [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/), and [JDistro](http://www.jdistro.com/) which have some elements of a pure-Java shell. The closest I ever found was [jsh](http://gerard.collin3.free.fr/) which was somebody's university project, as I recall, never met with any popularity, and was abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

I think this person would like to be able to do something like the following hypothetical example `java --cmd 'int x=5; System.out.print(x);'`

You can write your own program, let's call it `java-snippet`, which has a single command-line argument string called `code`. Insert the code snippet into the of temporary file.

```
...main(...) {
    //vvv your program inserts code here vvv
    //INSERT_CODE_MARKER
    //^^^                                ^^^
}
```

Then your `java-snippet` program compiles the temporary file and immediately runs it.

[edit: it seems the original poster did not in fact want this, but wants an **interactive java interpreter** -- leaving this answer here for posterity]

Answer (score 0):

> The Java Shell tool (JShell) is an interactive tool for learning the Java programming language and prototyping Java code. It was introduced in JDK 9. JShell is a Read-Evaluate-Print Loop tool (REPL), which evaluates declarations, statements, and expressions as they are entered and immediately shows the results. The tool is run from the command line.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/jshell/introduction-jshell.html